# How to enforce graph continuity constraint?

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, network-flow, mixed-integer-programming

I am working on a single source multiple destinations problem formulation using MILP. The network I have designed is as shown in the figure below [Graph Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yUNs.png). The objective function is to minimize the total travelling distance from source to all destination nodes which is defined as follows:

$\min \sum_{(i, j)\in N} T_{ij} x_{ij}$

The constraints I have defined are as follows:

$\sum_{i,j\in Edges} x_{ij} = \sum_{j,l\in Edges} x_{jl}$ for all intermediate nodes. It ensures path starts at origin and that each subsequent edge in the path is a continuation from the previous edge.

$\sum_{i,j\in Edges} x_{ij} = 1 $ For farthest destination node from all destinations

$\sum_{i,j\in Edges} x_{ij} >= 1 $ For intermediate destination nodes

$\sum_{i,j\in Edges} x_{ij} = 1$ for i is source node

The output shows discontinuous edges while computing the shortest path for all destinations. For example, O is the source node and A, C, and E. The output shows the edges:

O-C
C-E
A-B
B-A

The solution misses the edge from E-B. What should be the constraint to address this problem. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: What is $u_j$?  It doesn't seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: @saulspatz $u_j$ represents the destination nodes. I set a constraint that each destination node must be visited at least once. The intermediate destinations can be visited multiple times.

Comment: How does that enter into the MILP problem?  You minimize a function of the $x_{ij}$ subject to constraints on the $x_{ij}$.  I understand that part.   Then you define some variables $u_j$ that are never mentioned again.  How can they possibly affect the solution?  Are they defined in terms of the $x_ij$?

Comment: In the code, I have defined it using $x_{ij}$. I am writing two different constraints for the destinations. The code I am writing in docplex python as follows:
m.add_constraint(m.sum(x[(i,j)] for i,j in last_arc if j == final_END_NODE)== 1, ctname='last_arc')

for dd in remDst:
        m.add_constraint(m.sum(x[(i,j)] for i,j in subEdges if j==dd)>= 1, ctname='last_arc')

Comment: Please put the explanation in the body of the question, formatted so as to be easier to read.  What is `m`?  I don't see $u_i$ anywhere in your comment.  We shouldn't have to guess what you mean.

Comment: I have updated the question. $m$ represents the model defined in docplex code.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Think of sending one unit of flow from the source to each of the $d$ destination nodes. You can express the whole system of constraints uniformly as one constraint per node: outflow minus inflow equals $d$ for the source node, $0$ for the intermediate nodes, and $-1$ for the destination nodes.